# Upload button Issue with Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have upload button when user clicks on the upload then file gets uploaded there but when he cancel the file and choose another file that time file name doesnot show in chrome.In all browsers I can see that there is problem with Chrome only. here is my code

```
function myfunction() {
    var form = document.createElement("abcFORM");
    form.method = "post";
    form.style.display = "none";
    // adding some input elements to the form... 
    // ... 
    // adding the file input form.enctype = "multipart/form-data"; 
    var fileInputs = jQuery("input:file");
    fileInputs.each(function () {
        if (this.value != "") {form.appendChild(this);
        }
    });
    form.action = "my.servlet.path";
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: The first line in your function needs to be `var form = document.createElement("form");`

Comment: is `enter code here` a place holder? or is that actually in your code?

Comment: I guess its from the SO Code Sample Placeholder.